# reading specific integers from text file

Tags: c++, file-io, text-files

I have a text file that contains this information.

```
GO

pink colour 60 5 0

pink colour 80 10 0

chocs

red colour 100 15 1

red colour 120 15 1

man

blue colour 140 20 2

fast place

Brown colour 160 20 2

Going in plane

Green colour 280 35 5
```

Im trying to only extract the first integer of every line. the lines that dont have any integers I can skip.
so i can skip line 1 (`Go`)
but i need `60` from line 2.
and `80` from line 3.
skip line 4. etc...
but i dont know how. any help is much appreciated. thanks.

Comment: so far ive read the text file line by line in a for loop. and tried .substr. but the integars are not in the same place at every line to it only works for the first one.

Answer (score 0):

You could read the file one character at a time and check if that character is a digit. If it is then continue reading until you hit a character that isn't a digit. Then ignore everything until the character is a newline. It could look something like:

```
char buff;
std::fstream fin("file", std::fstream::in);

buff = fin.getchar();

// Read until end of file
while (buff != file.EOF)
{
    // if the char we read is a digit...
    if (isdigit(buff))
    {
        // Continue to read characters if they are an integer (same number)
        while (isdigit(buff))
        {
            // Store buff in some container
        }

        // Ignore until we hit the end of that line
        fin.ignore(256, '\n');      
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
using namespace std;

... ...

string str;
while (getline(file, str)) // read each line
{
    istringstream iss(str);
    int value;
    string temp;
    if (iss >> temp >> temp >> value) // try to read the value
    {
        // you got the value here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pseudocode:

```
read in a line, quit at EOF
for each line
    do a **string::find_first_of** for a digit
    if digit not found, go to read the next line
    do a **std::stoi** to convert to integer
    process the integer
```